# How to space verts along an edge loop without moving specific vert?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to space a series of vertices in a continuous edge loop so that they are evenly spaced. I would like to avoid moving a specific vertex for reasons of symmetry. The problem I'm having is that when using LoopTools > Space, there doesn't seem to be a way to fix a specific point:

In the following example, I am trying to preserve symmetry about the y-axis. I first try LoopTools > Space on the whole loop, but while it spaces the verts, it doesn't preserve symmetry. I then select each half of the loop and perform the LoopTools > Space operation on each in turn. This works, but is tedious.

[image]

But what about cases with an odd number of vertices? Or what if only one point is on the symmetry line, not two? Spacing by halves doesn't work in these cases.

Is there any way to fix a particular vertex in place, so that all other vertices are spaced relative to that one vertex? I would have hoped that LoopTools would simply automatically fix the active element, but that isn't the case.

And while my example above is a simplified case, frequently I am working with edge loops that aren't planar, so running LoopTools Space and then rotating the edge loop isn't a viable solution for these cases.

[image]

How would I evenly space the above vertices, for example, without moving the active element?